# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip height

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I'm generating dynamic tooltips using bootstrap 3.0.2. Some are able to fit in the default tooltip area without issue, and the tooltip automatically adjusts to heights so long as they are shorter than a certain size, but some are larger than the default allowable height and content spills out of my tooltip.

Code as follows. The max-height property is my insert, and seems to have no appreciable effect.

CSS

```
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col_one_fifth tooltip-test" id="tecc137" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="...">
    <div class="product-feature3"><h6 class="nopadding">Content</h6></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script> 
    $('#tecc137').tooltip({ html: true });
    $.ajax({url: 'url.php', type: 'POST', dataType: 'html', data: 'id=137', success: function(data){ $('#tecc137').attr('data-original-title', data ); } });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `height:300px` If it is fixed, or `min-height:300px` But not max height, which is not going to allow you to put it higher than that but niether setting it to 300px, just saying the max height allowed, but not the height it is going to take

Answering your comment, set the values to auto, and let min and max height between those values you said

Comment: Because it's dynamic it's not a fixed height, nor is minimum height what I want; ideally I would have a height that floats between 25px and 250px. If I specify min-height, I can set it so that all the content of my largest tooltip fits, but that approach leaves a big gap for tooltips with much less content.

Comment: So set them to auto @user3681179

Comment: Right, my css now looks like the following, but the tooltip still just stops after about 200px or so: .tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

Comment: And what happens to the content? Can you import it in a fiddle and i try to edit it through there? @user3681179

Comment: The content is put out just fine, but it doesn't fit in the content box. I'm a bit mystified, when I fiddle'd it, it expands just fine, but it's broken in my code. http://jsfiddle.net/YjC5Z/6/

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the fix was adding 
    display: inline-block; 
into the .tooltip-inner css in bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the content is sometimes there when the height is being calculated and sometimes it's not because it's asynchronously being injected.  I would just eliminate the data-toggle and manually call your tooltip after injecting the content in the success callback by adding the javascript method for showing a tooltip: `$('#tecc137').tooltip('show')`.  Then you know for sure that it will happen in that order.